# Import MongoDB output result into S3 bucket using Python

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

MongoDB Database Name :- `testdb`,

Collection Name :- `test_collection`

MongoDB command that I want to execute :-

```
db.getCollection('test_collection').find({ request_time: { $gte: new Date('2018-06-22'), $lt: new Date('2018-06-26') }});
```

In the documents of `test_collection`, there is a key called `request_time`. I want to fetch the documents in the time range `('2018-06-22')` and `('2018-06-26')`

MongoDB username :- user
MongoDB Password :- password

MongoDB is running on port 27017.

I need help in two things. I can connect into database but how to provide username and password in case of authentication. This is my Python code,

```
from pymongo import Connection
connection = Connection()
connection = Connection('localhost', 27017)
db = connection.testdb
collection = db.testcollection
for post in collection.find():
        print post
```

Another thing is,

I have a S3 bucket called, `mongodoc` . I want to query that mongo command and import the result documents into S3 bucket.

I can connect to S3 bucket by using a library called Boto ,

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(mongodoc)
destination = bucket.new_key()
destination.name = filename
destination.set_contents_from_file(myfile)
destination.make_public()
```

What is the recommended way to achieve this ?

Comment: Did you go through the documentation: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html which details how to authenticate with a username and password?

Answer (score 0):

In case of providing authentication, you have to provide the username and password along with the hostname,

```
connection=Connection(hostname="",username="",password="")
```

And for s3 connection, try using boto3 rather than using boto. boto3 provides a wide variety of functionality available for s3 client as well as resources. Once queried your mongodb results can be uploaded to your s3 buckets in the form of files.